# Kubuntu 12.04 VMware Workstation - No Window After Patch

Tags: 12.04, vmware

I installed VMware Workstation 7.1.5 on Kuuntu 12.04 (3.2.0-26). I have [patched](http://weltall.heliohost.org/wordpress/2012/01/26/vmware-workstation-8-0-2-player-4-0-2-fix-for-linux-kernel-3-2-and-3-3/) VMware.

The problem is that VMware does not show any window on start. I tried to see if there were any errors by starting up VMware on the command line and here is the output:

```
saadali@NX00064:~/Downloads/VMware Workstation/7.1.5$ vmware Logging
to /tmp/vmware-saadali/setup-22745.log

(vmware-modconfig:22631): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme
engine in module_path: "oxygen-gtk", filename:      
/lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic-pae/misc/vmmon.ko supported:     
external license:        GPL v2 description:    VMware Virtual Machine
Monitor. author:         VMware, Inc. srcversion:    
9869FFF2EA6B02360609EC6 depends:         vermagic:      
3.2.0-26-generic-pae SMP mod_unload modversions 686  filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic-pae/misc/vmnet.ko supported:     
external license:        GPL v2 description:    VMware Virtual
Networking Driver. author:         VMware, Inc. srcversion:    
DB41C2B4C15AC67851C744F depends:         vermagic:      
3.2.0-26-generic-pae SMP mod_unload modversions 686  filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic-pae/misc/vmblock.ko supported:     
external version:        1.1.2.0 license:        GPL v2 description:  
VMware Blocking File System author:         VMware, Inc. srcversion:  
BCAE10A6FFA68B7A1A93708 depends:         vermagic:      
3.2.0-26-generic-pae SMP mod_unload modversions 686  parm:           root:The directory the file system redirects to. (charp) filename:    
/lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic-pae/misc/vmci.ko supported:     
external license:        GPL v2 description:    VMware Virtual Machine
Communication Interface (VMCI). author:         VMware, Inc.
srcversion:     AF0065C2AA6B67906F2173C depends:         vermagic:    
3.2.0-26-generic-pae SMP mod_unload modversions 686  filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic-pae/misc/vsock.ko supported:     
external license:        GPL v2                                       
version:        1.0.0.0                                               
description:    VMware Virtual Socket Family                          
author:         VMware, Inc.                                          
srcversion:     CAEDBF81E2A76B434419B12                               
depends:        vmci                                                  
vermagic:       3.2.0-26-generic-pae SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic-pae/misc/vmmon.ko
supported:      external license:        GPL v2 description:    VMware
Virtual Machine Monitor. author:         VMware, Inc. srcversion:    
9869FFF2EA6B02360609EC6 depends:         vermagic:      
3.2.0-26-generic-pae SMP mod_unload modversions 686 

(vmware-tray:22654): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in
module_path: "oxygen-gtk",
```

Here is the log:

```
Jul 20 10:32:52.847: app-3076118208| Log for VMware Workstation
pid=22745 version=7.1.5 build=build-491717 option=Release Jul 20
10:32:52.847: app-3076118208| The process is 32-bit. Jul 20
10:32:52.847: app-3076118208| Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8 Jul
20 10:32:52.847: app-3076118208| Logging to
/tmp/vmware-saadali/setup-22745.log Jul 20 10:32:52.954:
app-3076118208| modconf query interface initialized Jul 20
10:32:52.955: app-3076118208| modconf library initialized
```

I would be thankful to anyone who can solve this problem. Vmware Player that installed with this version is running just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it from terminal with sudo. If window shows than you have rewrite permitions for files extracted from patch.

Comment: I ran it with sudo but the main window still does not show up. I have pasted the output here:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1101363/

Comment: is oxygen-gtk installed?